# Remove all but the first occurrence of a value in a nested Python dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

I have the following dictionary:

```
d1 = {'test': ['1', '2', '3'],
      'cool': ['7', '1'],
      'idk': ['3', '2', '7', '1'],
      'idc': ['8'],
      'hm': ['1', '4', '5']}
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
{'test': ['1', '2', '3'],
 'cool': ['7'],
 'idk': [''],
 'idc': ['8'],
 'hm': ['4','5']}
```

Here's the code i've tried:

```
result = {}

for key, value in d1.items():
    if value not in result.values():
        result[key] = value

print("result", str(result))
```

This isn't giving me the output i'm expecting. I'm trying to keep the first value and remove any occurrences of that value after that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the *idk* key to equate to an empty list rather than a list containing one empty string?

Comment: "value" is a list here. You have to create an inner loop to look at each item of the list and either remove unwanted items or create a new list with the desired items only. Maybe you should first write code for a single list to remove duplicates in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `set` variable that will contain all *seen* values so far:

```py
d1 = {
    "test": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "cool": ["7", "1"],
    "idk": ["3", "2", "7", "1"],
    "idc": ["8"],
    "hm": ["1", "4", "5"],
}

out, seen = {}, set()
for k, v in d1.items():
    tmp = []
    for vv in v:
        if vv not in seen:
            tmp.append(vv)
            seen.add(vv)
    out[k] = tmp or [""]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "test": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "cool": ["7"],
    "idk": [""],
    "idc": ["8"],
    "hm": ["4", "5"],
}
```

---

Alternative without `set`:

```py
out = {}
for k, v in d1.items():
    for vv in v:
        if not any(vv == vvv for l in out.values() for vvv in l):
            out.setdefault(k, []).append(vv)
    out[k] = out.get(k, [""])
print(out)
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:-

```
d1 = {'test': ['1', '2', '3'],
      'cool': ['7', '1'],
      'idk': ['3', '2', '7', '1'],
      'idc': ['8'],
      'hm': ['1', '4', '5']}

kv = []
d2 = {}
for k, v in d1.items():
    ta=[]
    for n in v:
        if not n in kv:
            kv.append(n)
            ta.append(n)
    d2[k]=ta
print(d2)
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot. I appreciate it.